# Getting error when using type "React.ReactNode" to children. Which type should I use?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, children

Getting error message when using function `LoaderIndicator()`, which renders children, when `loading = false`, see code below. The error appeared when I used `React.ReactNode` instead of type `any`, but normally I use `React.ReactNode` as type for children. This is the error I get:

`'LoaderIndicator' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type '{}' is not a valid JSX element. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key. ts(2786)`

I don't know how to fix this error, I have tried almost everything, is anyone able to help? :)

```
export type LoaderIndicatorProps = {
  loading: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode; 
};
export function LoaderIndicator(props: LoaderIndicatorProps) {
  const { loading, children } = props;

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Icon />
          <h3 style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>Wait for a moment...</h3>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return children;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI if you use `React.FC<{ loading: boolean }>` as the type for your component function, it adds the `children` prop for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

React components should return `JSX.Element`. As you can see, your children are of type `React.ReactNode`, so straight returning them will not work. You need to wrap them inside an element or React.Fragment:

```
type TestComponentProps = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

function TestComponent(props: TestComponentProps) {
    return <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

Comment: This makes the linter say "Fragments should contain more than one child - otherwise, there’s no need for a Fragment at all." :(